# How could a user (moderator) with 98 reputation points have downvoted?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, privileges, moderator-abilities

First of all, the point of this question is just to understand how SE works. I have no other motive with this question. I'm just trying to learn about the finer details.

When I came across this [user](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1690/adam-lear?tab=topactivity) while browsing Travel Meta, I became curious as to why he had 98 rep rather than at least 101 from the reputation bonus. I thought he must have received downvotes, but then I noticed he doesn't have any answers or questions, so this can be ruled out.

It turns out he has actually downvoted four times. I guess if three of those were on answers, it would explain how he lost 3 rep. But how could he even downvote while being below 125 rep?

He has not posted any bounties.

Again, just trying to learn about how the system works. I obviously don't care about this particular account.

Comment: I suspect that the rep limitation does not apply to Stack Exchange developers which are also moderators.

Comment: because he's a Diamond Mod? they have all Mod Powers regardless of Rep

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Oh, so moderators can downvote regardless of reputation?

Comment: I can't find any resources to confirm it, regular moderators are generally required to have more rep to be elected, but most-likely.

Comment: User gains 25 rep, downvotes two posts, loses two rep. User's question (5 upvotes) or combination of answers and question are self-deleted. All rep gained is lost, but the 2 rep lost when downvoting remains.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, this is possible. Although to nitpick, it would have had to be three downvotes.

Comment: I didn't register the 4 downvotes the user made, I was just thinking how someone could end up with 98 rep but with no posts. EDIT: He's an SO mod, probably means he has special privileges. Note the diamond  even if he's a member of a different and totally unrelated sister site, travel.SE. Best check out if his diamond is present in all his accounts.

Comment: 162 accounts, and he's a mod on all of them http://stackexchange.com/users/37099/adam-lear?tab=accounts

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, Adam is an SE employee, so I believe he's a mod network wide.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[o hai](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX6M9.jpg) :)

Diamond mods bypass reputation requirements for privileges. I'm also a developer working *at* Stack Overflow under the Q&A umbrella team (not every developer here has "developer" access to all Q&A sites, which is confusing, but hopefully you get the idea), so even without a diamond, I'd have the same access to downvotes.

The only time that could *really* matter is on brand new sites. Q&A developers and community managers employed by Stack Overflow get diamonds on all sites, so they could downvote anywhere, in theory. Communities have non-employee moderators appointed shortly after the start of the private beta, and it'd be fairly unusual for one of those to be below 125 reputation required for downvoting. It *could* happen, but it just doesn't tend to be a thing in practice.

Personally, I tend to be very careful with my downvotes on sites I'm not usually involved with, especially since my reputation and a lack of other participation obviously give them away. Once in a while, though, there's an obviously unhelpful answer...

Comment: I think I saw somewhere SE employee saying he can't answer a protected question without the required reputation, but can't find anything now. Is this still happening?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Probably. That's not a privilege, it's a direct rep check. Same goes for posting on child metas, though we may have fixed that one by now. Not sure since I never run into it. :)

Comment: But answering protected questions is clearly mentioned in [Remove New User Restrictions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) privilege, so how come it's not a privilege? So to this day, you can't post an answer to protected questions [here](http://law.stackexchange.com/), for example?

Answer (score 12):

Moderators always have all privileges; reputation does not matter. Normally a user wouldn't have a diamond if they didn't have a bit of reputation that put them above most of the basic privilege levels. Stack Exchange staff are an exception, though. Many of us have diamonds everywhere and thus have access to all tools even with only the association bonus. Adam Lear in particular is a developer here, which is why he has diamonds on all sites.